# Object Not Updated in Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

I'm trying to create a unit test using Moq and xUnit. The operation is very straightforward: calculate the number of days in a date range and update an object property. This works in integration testing, however the object property is not updated in my unit test

Unit Test:

```
[Fact]
public void Bill_DayCount_IsCorrect()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<IRepository>();

    Bill bill = new Bill
    {
        StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2/1/2018"),
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse("3/1/2018"),
    };

    // Act
    mockRepo.Object.GetBillDayCount(bill);

    // Assert
    // Here the bill.DayCount value = 0
    Assert.Equal(28, bill.DayCount);
}
```

The method in the repo:

```
public Bill GetBillDayCount(Bill bill)
{
    bill.DayCount = (bill.EndDate - bill.StartDate).Days;
    return bill;
}
```

Comment: Your test case doesn't make any sense. Mocking is a useful technique for unit testing components which have a dependency on an external component, and you want to control how that external component behaves. In your example you've created a mock of the `IRepository` interface which means that your component under test most be a different class. The `mockRepo.Object.GetBillDayCount(bill)` call doesn't make any sense since there's no implementation behind the `GetBillDayCount` method.

Comment: @botond.botos In the case presented, the `Bill` object was dependent on a method from the `Repository` class, so this test was meant to judge interactions between components. However, after your comment, it has since been refactored to have the `GetBillDayCount` be a method within the `Bill` class which is a more natural place for it. Thanks

Comment: No issue with the downvotes, but please leave some feedback to help me better understand the issue and why it deserves a downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to mock the class which is the target of your test. You can use the concrete implementation of `Repository`.

You only need to mock the external dependencies that the target class uses.

**Interface**

```
public interface IRepository
{
    Bill GetBillDayCount(Bill bill);
}
```

**Class**

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public Bill GetBillDayCount(Bill bill)
    {
        bill.DayCount = (bill.EndDate - bill.StartDate).Days;
        return bill;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
[Fact]
public void Bill_DayCount_IsCorrect()
{
    // Arrange
    var repository = new Repository();

    var bill = new Bill
    {
        StartDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2018"),
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse("29/1/2018"),
    };

    // Act
    var result = repository.GetBillDayCount(bill);

   // Assert
   Assert.Equal(28, result.DayCount);
}
```